# PHP set value of text box equal to form variable

Tags: php

I am simply trying to enter a word or number into the first text box and upon clicking submit have that word stored in a variable and then echoed into the second text box. This is the code I have but it is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $one = "";
        if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){
            $one = $_POST["inputOne"];
        }
    ?>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="inputOne">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
        <input type="text" name="output" value="<?php echo $one; ?>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you name the this file as `index.php`?

Comment: your code works..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code.  In what way does it "not work"?  What specifically happens?

Comment: @DollyAswin yes

Comment: @David when i load the page in my browser and enter a value into the first text box and then hit submit, the page reloads but nothing appears in the second text box

Comment: @j.richards: When you view the page source in your browser, do you see just the HTML or do you also see PHP code?

Comment: @David when in view source in chrome it is not showing the php, just empty head tags

Comment: @j.richards: Are there any errors in your PHP logs?  Can you try a PHP file with just a single simple line of code, like an echo of a literal value?

Comment: @David the following seems to work fine. im not sure how to check my php logs <html>
    <head>
        <?php
            echo "test";
            $var = 5;
            echo $var;
        ?>
    </head>
</html>

Comment: This code works for me, too.  The only thing I can think of, though it should be very unlikely, is the page getting cached such that you're not re-executing the PHP.  This really shouldn't be the case, but maybe add `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">` to your header block, be sure the page is completely reloaded, and try again.

Comment: @JHB it seems whatever the issue is is related to phpstorm and running the page from its built in web server simulator. Loading my. Page through WAMP it executes as intended

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `index.php` from the `action`, to just blank? At first it didn't work, but then I removed the index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $one = "";
        if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){
            $one = $_POST["inputOne"];
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="inputOne">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
        <input type="text" name="output" value="<?php echo $one; ?>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST["inputOne"])){ $one = $_POST["inputOne"]; 
}else{$one = 'No value was sent for inputOne';}
```

...with this your php will let you know if a value for inputOne was never received in the first place.

Honestly.. for what you are trying to achieve, your code should look more like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $one = "";
        if (isset($_POST["inputOne"])){
            $one = $_POST["inputOne"];
        }else{$one = 'No value received for one';}
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="inputOne">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
        <input type="text" name="output" value="<?php echo $one; ?>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```